# Having issue with getting my file to print to console

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I have a data structure assignment were the code has to read the text data from a text file and print it onto the screen. The code that I wrote says that the build was a success but the text file itself doesn't print. What do I do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream

public class readFile{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
        Scanner file = null;
        int textFile;
        try{
            fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("file1.txt");
            file = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
            while(file.hasNextInt()){
                textFile = file.nextInt();
                System.out.println("file1.txt");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(textFile);

Comment: An empty `catch` block is usually not a good idea. Try adding `e.printStackTrace();` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `System.out.println("file1.txt");` by `System.out.println(textFile);`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you have the "file1.txt" saved in the correct location. As is, you are just passing the String "file1.txt" rather than the file object which was not yet created. (See line 13 of this code below)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

    public class readFile
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
      {
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
        Scanner file = null;
        int textFile;
        File file1 = new File("file1.txt");
      try
      {
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(file1); 
        file = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
        System.out.println("Reading file...");
        while(file.hasNextInt())
        {
          textFile = file.nextInt();
          System.out.println(textFile);
          System.out.println("Scanning a line..");
        }
        file.close();
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Exception handled");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is possible to edit your [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867483/having-issue-with-getting-my-file-to-print-to-console/65867990#65867990). Just click on the _Edit_ link below the answer text. If you haven't already done so, consider taking the [tour].

Answer (score -1):

You can use print statements to help see where the code is breaking. It looks like you have an IO Exception (input/output). Also, you should want to close the Scanner object.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    public class readFile
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
      {
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
        Scanner file = null;
        int textFile;
     
      try
      {
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("file1.txt"); 
        file = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
        System.out.println("Reading file...");
        while(file.hasNextInt())
        {
          textFile = file.nextInt();
          System.out.println(textFile);
          System.out.println("Scanning a line..");
        }
        file.close();
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Exception handled");
      }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think that `e.printStackTrace()` is preferable to `System.out.println("Exception handled");` It is also preferable to put `file.close();` in a `finally` block. Actually, [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is probably better.